# Permutations to divide a solid

Tags: permutations, factorial, solid-geometry

I have a 3-dimensional cuboid, with dimensions 2x2x1. I wish to divide this into smaller EQUAL sized cuboids of size 2x1x1. Then I want to extend this case for larger cuboids, assuming that equal smaller cuboids are possible. What are the possible number of ways to do this?
I thought of this logic, but I don't think it is correct.

We will have a cuboid of volume 4, have to divide this into 2 cuboids of volume 2.
Possible options are 2!, (choose any 1 dimension in which I keep the 2 as it is, and divide the other one) However I feel that this logic is incorrect, especially when I go for cases like 2x2x2 or 2x2x4 or even larger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The exact nature of what you're asking isn't clear. Are you asking how many ways you can split larger rectangular prisms into two equal halves, as long as the halves have integral dimensions, or something else?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly my question. However, I am taking the particular case, where my cuboid has dimensions 2x2xn, and I want to divide this into equal smaller cuboids having volume of 2 with integral dimensions. (1x1x2 or 1x2x1 or 2x1x1 etc)

Comment: Then that's an entirely different question. It's essentially the 3D version of the domino tiling question: sample references [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664113/count-the-ways-to-fill-a-4-times-n-board-with-dominoes) and [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/domino-tilings.pdf).

Comment: Okay! Thankyou. Further question, could this be extended to any number of dimensions, like it is extended from 2 dimensions to 3 dimensions here.

Comment: Yep. Most questions you ask about some situation in some $n$-space, unless predicated upon some specific characteristic of $n$, are extensible through $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: 1 final thing! If you could explain this to me.
Lets say I have in 5-dimensional space, with dimensions 2x2x2x2x1.
I want to divide this into equal parts with integral dimensions 1x1x1x1x2 (where the order of these dimensions is trivial, (the product of the dimensions should be 2)). How can the number of possible ways this can be done calculated? I am reading about the domino tiling, but extending this to such a large case is tough, which is why I asked for your help to just help explain 1 example, that way I'd probably get it better. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33877/discussion-between-someone1-and-pockets).