# Simplify system of 3 equations of 3 recursive functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to simplify this system into one equation of `f` only?

f(N) = f(N-1) + f(N-2) + 2*g(N) + h(N)

g(N) = f(N-2) + g(N-1)

h(N) = f(N-2) + h(N-2)

Initial values if needed:
f(1) = 2
f(2) = 5
g(2) = 1
g(3) = 2
h(2) = 1
h(3) = 1

---

*I'm not sure it is possible. The simplification I have is:*

()=(−1)+5(−2)+(−3)−(−4)

*But it maybe includes some additional inputs.*

Comment: It is part of the bigger problem. Someone else solved the bigger problem differently then I did, the solution should be the same. So either this is the only possible simplification, or is one solution that satisfies all 3 equations. I also have initial values, if needed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338215/calculate-number-of-tiling-combinations-recursively this is my way. This is the other solution https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664236/504321

Comment: I added initial values, you think they can help?

Comment: @PeterForeman Check a very ingenious answer below :). The guy owned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with 
$$\begin{align}
&f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + 2·g(n) + h(n)
\\&-\\
&f(n - 2) = f((n - 2) - 1) + f((n - 2) - 2) + 2·g(n - 2) + h(n - 2)
\end{align}$$
And obtain 
$$
f(n) = - f(n - 4) - f(n - 3) + 2·f(n - 2) + f(n - 1) - 2·g(n - 2) + 2·g(n) - h(n - 2) + h(n)
$$
We can substitute $h(n)-h(n-2)$ in the equation and get
$$
f(n) = - f(n - 4) - f(n - 3) + 2·f(n - 2) + f(n - 1) - 2·g(n - 2) + 2·g(n)+f(n-2)
$$

Now all that's left to eliminate are the summands $- 2·g(n - 2) + 2·g(n)$.

Using the recurrence $g(n) = f(n - 2) + g(n - 1)$ this becomes:
$$- 2·g(n - 2) + 2·f(n - 2) + 2·g(n - 1)$$

Which, using the same recurrence (shifted by $n\mapsto n-1$) becomes
$$ 2·f(n - 2) + 2·f(n-3)$$

And so, we obtain the recurrence:

$$
f(n) = - f(n - 4) - f(n - 3) + 2·f(n - 2) + f(n - 1)+ 2·f(n - 2) + 2·f(n-3)+f(n-2)
$$

Or, simplified
$$f(n) = f(n - 1)+ 5·f(n - 2)+ f(n - 3) - f(n - 4)  $$

So, your reduction was correct.

Comment: I cannot believe this is possible. I have to review this calmly now.

Comment: How did you get the third line. "And obtain...". Did you subracted second equation from first?

Comment: Exactly, I took your first recurrence equation, let's call it $R_1(n)$, and calculated $R_1(n)-R_1(n-2)$

Comment: Cool. I though that minus between the first and the second is a random underscore :D. YOU SIR ARE A GENTLEMAN AND A SCHOLAR!

Comment: As a bonus please check the links where my question originally comes from:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338215/calculate-number-of-tiling-combinations-recursively
And why I assumed it can be reduced: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664236/504321
I think I will give my own answer to that question, including your simplification.

Comment: That problem looks quite elaborate. But given that your idea is similar to that of the accepted answer, and especially as the recursion is correct as well, it is extremely likely that your reduction was correct

Comment: When I saw the accepted answer examining more tilings than I did, I thought more relations are needed to "unify" the recursive relations into single relation of a single function. And I'm happy knowing I was so close to the solution :)